# Why won't my matplotlib subplots horizontal distance get any smaller? wspace non-functional

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, imshow

I can't seem to shrink the distance between my two columns and the subplots.adjust function doesn't seem to allow it to be smaller. I have used the hspace and wspace commands to try to force it, however it doesn't seem to work. I have

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, dpi=300)
fontprops = fm.FontProperties(size=6,weight='bold')

for i in range((4)):
    for j in range(2):
        axs[i][j].set_yticks([])
        axs[i][j].set_xticks([])


axs[0,0].imshow(ITO10_Dimer1SI_Linear_Norm,cmap=ice_map1)
axs[0,0].text(38,4,'565 meV', color='w',fontsize=6,fontweight='bold')
axs[1,0].imshow(ITO10_Dimer1SI_Parallel_Norm,cmap=ice_map1)
axs[1,0].text(38,4,'785 meV', color='w',fontsize=6,fontweight='bold')
axs[2,0].imshow(ITO10_Dimer1SI_aParallel_Norm,cmap=ice_map1)
axs[2,0].text(38,4,'910 meV', color='w',fontsize=6,fontweight='bold')
axs[3,0].imshow(ITO10_Dimer1SI_aLinear_Norm,cmap=ice_map1)
axs[3,0].text(38,4,'970 meV', color='w',fontsize=6,fontweight='bold')

axs[0,1].imshow(BondIP_Norm,cmap='hot') 
axs[1,1].imshow(ParaIP_Norm,cmap='hot')
axs[2,1].imshow(ParaOP_Norm,cmap='hot') 
axs[3,1].imshow(BondOP_Norm,cmap='hot')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05,wspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: the output]

Comment: Because you’ve set your aspect ratio to one.

Comment: I've tried it with and without setting the aspect equal to 1 and it doesn't make a difference. I have removed that from the code in the question though, thank you for point it out.

Comment: That’s because the default for imshow is 1.  Change aspect=‘auto’